# How do I access a public page variable of the only page from the master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a page - only ONE page for the entire site:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class CMSPageViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int myPageID;

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Get stuff from the database

         myPageID = 1;

         // Set the Page.MasterPageFile
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fill in the page contents
        // This looks for and fills in asp:ContentPlaceHolder controls based on ID
    }
}
```

And the master page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Standard_Page : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int myID = (this.Page as CMSPageViewer).myPageID;
    }
}
```

How can I access ID from the MasterPage that is used?

Casting the page doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CMSPageViewer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: for this to work CMSPageViewer needs to be a "real" class (not a partial .aspx thingy) defined either in App_Code or in some Class Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a variable in your master page. Give it proper getter/setters. In each page call the master.setter and "pass the variable into" the master page.

At the very least you're going about it wrong, but this is what you have to do.

Referencing "ASP.NET 3.5 Unleashed" [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0672330113](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330113) section in Chapter 5 pages 255 - 260 for modifying `Master` properties based on the `Page` being interpreted.

Again, Referencing ASP.NET 3.5 Unleashed Chapter 6 which starts off:

> Themes are different than Master Pages. A Master Page enables you to share content across multiple pages in a website. A Theme, on the other hand, enables you to control the appearance of the content.

So in other words, you're not supposed to use a Master Page as a Theme, the two work together.

Do you want me to keep going? I've got a few other books. I've done exactly what you're trying to do (modify the master based on the content) and at the time I knew it was a hack, but I did it because I had to. So what I'm telling you is what I did, which is what works.

Now please, again, tell me that what I'm suggesting can't be done. I'll go find some more references that will explain why you can't cast to a Page from within the Master.

---

For those looking to lay the smack down on my turning to a book for reference, note that that's how the big boys play, it's how the people who get the actual contracts play, and it's how you inform your boss. It's a book. That's what they're for. Additionally, Stephen Walther is not a nobody, he was a Senior Product Manager for the ASP.NET team. So he knows what the hell he's talking about. I would listen to his advice. Hell, I bought his book didn't I?

Comment: This is the opposite of what I'm asking. The master page is a theme. there could be 3-4 master pages on a site, each site has its on master pages. 99 times out of 100 the master page needs to know nothing about the page itself. there is no special requirement for the master page to work i would rather not require a method/variable exist on all possible master pages is they dont need it. That is why I'm asking... How can a master page access a variable from a page?

Comment: It's not the opposite of what you're asking, you're asking for a way for the master page to know what the inner page is doing. You can't assume all pages will have the same type (which you'll need to cast to if you're doing what @cybernate is suggesting) ... give me a few minutes to go dig up a textual reference (aka a book)

Comment: All you're master-pages should inherit from some base master-class which contains the logic to fetch this id. Then you can have a zillion different themes, just inheriting from this one base class so the logic doesn't get duplicated.

Comment: +1 to this approach. I have used it in the past to adjust nav elements in a master page.

Comment: @drachenstern - I have not deleted any answers or comments. I have been reading them all.

Comment: Well there are some curious statements made by other posters that seem to lack context :\

Answer (score 2):

I dislike the design, but if there is only a single page in the application, then this begins to make more sense.

In fact, this is not what master pages are for. This is what themes are for.

Comment: every page on my site used CMSPageViewer, its all filled in from the database.  The master page is set in code and can be different depending on the page settings. The only stable item in the CMSPageViewer page. so if there is page ID that I need to access from the master page, I need to get it from the CMSPageViewer class.

Comment: @Justin: it still seems like a pretty goofy thing to do.

Comment: @Justin808 - I agree that this isn't the best design.  If it is a requirement of the master page that it know the Id, then the master page should do the work getting it, not expect the page to do it and then access it from there.  This is the wrong way around.

Comment: The master page is being used as a theme, putting all the work into the theme would be a little odd. Having the master page access a variable doesn't seems to outlandish to me.

Comment: All you're master-pages should inherit from some base master-class which contains the logic to fetch this id. Then you can have a zillion different themes, just inheriting from this one base class so the logic doesn't get duplicated.

Comment: @Justin: please update your question with the fact that you only have a single page. This is an important part of your question, and something that very few web applications have.

Comment: I would have deleted my question, but wanted to leave the comments.

Comment: If you're swapping master pages (which I've done before) it would be best to make them inherit from your own base master page that has common logic such as this requirement.  Then make your master pages inherit from your base one, not System.Web.MasterPage.

Comment: @john wouldn't say only a few applications use this concept... basically ALL .net cms systems rely on the concept of ONE page-class for displaying the content and then masters is a way of choosing different templates/layouts for a page.

Comment: Well thats what you get for opening a page, getting a coffee, and coming back.  A lot can happen in 5 minutes.  Sorry Pauli - you got the suggestion out first ;)

Comment: @Pauli: what I mean is that, unless the question says there's only one page, everyone reading this "ASP.NET" question will assume there is more than one page.

Comment: @Pauli the difference is that ASP.NET has a Theme class in addition to a Master class.

Comment: @drachenstern i know, but its not my understanding at all that the asp.net theme feature (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) is what Justin808 is referring to when saying that "master page is being used as a theme". Themes and masterpages have no relation as such.

Comment: @Pauli ~ I know, hence see my edits on my answer ;) ~ Additionally, I still think he's engineering it wrong, and would like to help him re-engineer it, but I think he's decided or forced into doing it by this wrong method. At any rate, the pages I reference in that book will help him even with this method, like choosing a new Master from within the Page if he felt the need.

Answer (score 0):

In your master page use this:

```
(this.Page as CMSPageViewer ).ID
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CMSPageViewer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add the full namespace of CMSPageViewer to the above.

Comment: nothing is rapped in a namespace. what is the "default" namespace?

Comment: @Cybernate this will never work. Consider that a master page is a sort of wrapper for many pages. I see where you're going with this, but it won't work.

Comment: Am not saying whether it is right approach or not. I am just saying that technically it is possible.

Comment: @cybernate yeah if he only has to work with one page for the master page ... negates the point of a master page tho

Comment: for this to work CMSPageViewer needs to be a "real" class (not a partial .aspx thingy) defined either in App_Code or in some Class Library.

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you use a session variable that you could access from both the page and the master page.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
```

Comment: thats a violation of the whole OO principle

Comment: But, what's so OO about the whole situation here? At least its a cleaner way of accessing data, if not misused